# Joomla blank page after migration?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, category, migration, error-pages

I have Joomla 3.3.1 version
After migrating the web site to another host (with IIS server) I had a problem with blank pages when I click on a menu

The home page is displayed well, the problem is just in the menus links.

This is some errors:

- Notice: Undefined index: id in
  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ormvag.ma\httpdocs\components\com_falang\helpers\falang.class.php
  on line 230
- Warning:
  file(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ormvag.ma\httpdocs/administrator/components/com_sef/sef.xml):
  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ormvag.ma\httpdocs\components\com_sef\joomsef.php
  on line 2824
- Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in
  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ormvag.ma\httpdocs\components\com_sef\joomsef.php
  on line 2824
- Warning:
  file(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ormvag.ma\httpdocs/administrator/components/com_sef/sef.xml):
  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ormvag.ma\httpdocs\components\com_sef\joomsef.php
  on line 2824
- Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in
  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ormvag.ma\httpdocs\components\com_sef\joomsef.php
  on line 2824
- Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
  File(/../../../plugins/system/jmframework/includes/assets/template/bootstrap/less/reset.less.less)
  is not within the allowed path(s):
  (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/ormvag.ma\;C:\windows\Temp) in
  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ormvag.ma\httpdocs\plugins\system\jmframework\includes\libraries\less\lessc.inc.php
  on line 300

**Web config gile ( web.config ):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
           <rules>
               <rule name="Joomla! Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\)" ignoreCase="false" />
                       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(&gt;|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(&lt;|%3E)" />
                       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
                       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="CustomResponse" url="index.php" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
               </rule>
               <rule name="Joomla! Rule 2">
                   <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                     <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/index.php" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: IIS is not recommended for Joomla. It may cause some errors. But try to check if your webconfig file is OK and rebuild the menu. https://github.com/joomlagovbr/joomla-3.x/blob/master/web.config.txt

Comment: I have already changed this file but not working